# how to define a file path in java to make it ready for production phase?

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

I am writing a program in java with netbeans IDE which receives a jasper report *.jrxml and then displays the report for the user. I wrote the following line of code for the file path

```
String reportSource = "src\\jasper-reports\\report.jrxml";
```

but when I move the **dist** folder in some other place and try to run the jar file inside it, my program can not find the report.

my problem is that were should I put the *.jrxml file and how to define it's path in my program so that when I want to give my software to someone else it runs without any errors (e.g. the program can find the file)

Comment: You need to include it in your final jar as a resource

Comment: thanx, but how should I wrote its path in reportSource field?

Comment: Google how to use jar resources. You can read it as a stream from your jar

Answer (score 1):

avoid using absolute paths. try to include the file as a resource in your netbeans project. then in your code you can search for and load the file as

```
new InputStreamReader((Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/report.jrxml")))
```

something like that depending on where the file resides in your project

Answer (score 0):

it's more recommended using one of the two approaches:

1. pass the locations/paths as a **-D**property=value in the Java application launcher command line http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/java.htm
2. store it the locations/paths in a configurations file with a unique key and edit the file accordingly for different environments, 
   e.g.this files always stored in ${HOME}/config_files/ directory

absolute paths considered a bad practice